# Java Serialization : How use Object InputStream / Object Output Stream

Tags: java, oop, serialization, deserialization

i'm learning Java language thanks "to Deitel & Deitel How To Program in Java 10ed".
But i have some problem about understanding the stream of object in file .
I understand that `ObjectOutputStream` enables you to write Object in file. 
Using Book's words : `ObjectOutputStream` is initialized with a Stream Object , because it writes byte in the file.
Instead `ObjectInputStream` enable you to read Object in the file .
And ObjectInputStream is initialized with a a Stream Object for catch  bytes from file.
But what is a Stream object ?
This is the code to Output:

```
output = new ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream( Paths.get("clients.ser")));
```

this is the code to input:

```
input = new ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("clients.ser"));
```

What is `Files.newOutputStream`? What Does it return ?

Thanks for Attention 
(if you tell me books for learning java better than mine it's very good!)

(i'm italian, so maybe my english would be not so good )

Comment: A very important source of information is the Javadoc of the classes : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newInputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method opens or creates a file and return an output stream that may be used to write bytes to the file. This returned stream is threadsafe.

For detailed description please visit:
[Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)

Comment: Is correct think that say "return an output stream" is  like say "return a reference to file" ? 
Maybe my problem is that i started to program in C so it easier for me think to a a FILE pointer

Comment: Yes you are right, it will return a reference to file.

Answer (score 0):

`Files.newOutputStream` creates an OutputStream object enabling you to write to a `File` on the `Path` denoted by `path` argument of `newOutputStream(Path path, OpenOption... options)`.